# Deploying project with modules to GAE Flex

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, module

I have a Flask project with the following structure:

```
- /
  - app.yaml
  - app/
    - __init__.py
    - main.py (imports 'helper')
    - helper.py
```

`main.py` does an `import helper`. Locally I run the app by executing `python app/main.py` from the root directory and all is well.

However, when I run `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` I get `ImportError: No module named 'helper'`.

How can I 'register' the `helper` so that it deploys?

Answer (score 0):

The way you execute the application right now is not loading `app` as a module, it just executes `app/main.py` as a standalone file, with '.' pointing to the module's top dir, which is not where `helper.py` exists. Thus the error.

Your `main.py` (the one invoked to execute your app) should be side-by-side the `app.yaml` file (which identifies your app/service top level dir). From that `main.py` you can then load/invoke your modules as needed, say via `import app.helper` for example.